# Row deletion animation issue with swipe to delete

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am implementing swipe to delete feature on one of my table that uses custom table view cells. The issue I am facing is when I tap on "Delete" button, I see a weird transition while cell is being removed.

Below is my code in "commitEditingStyle" and also see the attached screenshot I captured while row is being removed.

PS: I have tried with all types of row removal animation styles but no luck.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)iEditingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iIndexPath {
    if (iEditingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete && iTableView == self.temporaryCartTable) {
        if (self.temporaryCartTable.frame.size.height == kMyAppCartTableViewExpandedHeight) {

            [self.temporaryCartTable beginUpdates];
            [self.temporaryCartTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: iIndexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

            MyAppCartInfo *aMyAppCartInfo = [self cart];

            if (([[aMyAppCartInfo.tempProducts allKeys] count] > iIndexPath.row) && [aMyAppCartInfo.tempProducts containsObjectForKey:[[aMyAppCartInfo.tempProducts allKeys] objectAtIndex:iIndexPath.row]]) {
                [aMyAppCartInfo.tempProducts removeObjectForKey:[[aMyAppCartInfo.tempProducts allKeys] objectAtIndex:iIndexPath.row]];
            }

            [self.temporaryCartTable endUpdates];
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return (iTableView == self.temporaryCartTable) ? YES : NO;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iIndexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iIndexPath {

    if (iTableView == self.temporaryCartTable) {
        if (self.isTempCartCell)
            return 92.0;
        else
            return 58.0;
    } else {
        return 58.0;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should remove the object from your data source before `beginUpdates`.

Comment: You might also want to look at the TLIndexPathTools library which handles this logic for you.

Comment: @AaronBrager I tried by removing the object from your data source before `beginUpdates` but got same results.

Comment: What is the point of this conditional: `if (([[aMyAppCartInfo.tempProducts allKeys] count] > iIndexPath.row) && [aMyAppCartInfo.tempProducts containsObjectForKey:[[aMyAppCartInfo.tempProducts allKeys] objectAtIndex:iIndexPath.row]])1`?  Can you remove it entirely?  I can't really debug any further than this since you're not showing your other tableview delegate methods.

Comment: @AaronBrager That IF condition was just a safe check. I tried removing this and I still see same UI glitch. I have put other tableview delegate methods in my question above. Please let me know if you are looking for some more methods.

Comment: Do you see the odd lines if you don't use custom cells?

Comment: @NonlinearIdeas I did not try that but the reason for using custom cell is that I am expanding my cell on tap on it with few more UI widgets on it. So, I have to have a custom UITableView cell.

Comment: @Abhinav I apologize for not being clear.  I meant to try the standard cells temporarily so you could better isolate if the problem is something left over from the custom cell instead of their use in the table.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following method implementation to your `UITableViewDelegate`

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
          editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this did not help. I see the same weird animation with this implementation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[self.temporaryCartTable setRowHeight:xxx]` instead of using the delegate `rowHeightAtIndexPath`. After the row is deleted and there is no other rows in the table, the delegate will not called and your table view's row height will be retrieved by its property (hence the default height). Plus, using this method from the delegate affects the performance.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is having this, the problem in my case was `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` When cells have dynamic size delete animation behaves strange. In my case the solution was to use a different approach and not spend time investigating. But you can test it and see results. Assign a fixed height for cells:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = Constant;
```

comment out `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. And animations should be ok now.

I know this is not the solution but may still help someone.